# Calling a referenced dll from WebAPI works locally but not on server

Tags: class, reference, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebAPI that I have Cors enabled.

My webAPI references a Class library that I do a lot of the processing in.

calls between the WebAPI and Class library and also some calls inside the class library are

throwing this error...

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
"ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","StackTrace":"   
at RCIS.MappingServices.WebAPI.Utilities.SQL.SQLInsertObjects(Int32 TypeMapId, Int32 GrowerId, Int32 CropYear, String NAME, String SHAPE, String CREATED_BY, String CREATED_DATETIME, String MODIFIED_BY, String MODIFIED_DATETIME, String IsDELETED)\r\n   
at RCIS.MappingServices.WebAPI.Controllers.PostObjectsController.GET(String TypeMapId, String GrowerId, String CropYear, String NAME, String SHAPE)\r\n   
at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, 
IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"}
```

This Only seems to be happening when calling the class library from the server (i.e.) I enter a URL into Chrome calling the WebAPI method and get this error back.

If I use all primitive types in the WebAPI and In the class library I get a success message back.

If you have any questions please let me know.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated I have been trying to solve this for 2 days!!!

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the only thing you are passing is string values.

Answer (score 0):

Make an ErrorHelper:

```
public class ErrorHelper : IHttpActionResult
{
    private HttpRequestMessage Request { get; }
    private HttpStatusCode statusCode;
    private string message;

    public ErrorHelper(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message)
    {
        this.Request = request;
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Request.CreateErrorResponse(statusCode, message));
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var person = _repository.GetPersonId(id);
        if (person == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(person);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new ErrorHelper(Request, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

This will give you the Exception details. You probably haven't got a component installed on the Server, like a Database Driver or something like that.